# Azure App Logic - How to page files on blob storage

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I have a blob with over 5000 files. Checking the documentation and limited by pagination this amount.

I'm trying to do a paging in the APP LOGIC but I'm not able to do this loop. When I get the PAGE MARKER it returns strange information and I don't understand how to put it in the loop

How do I adjust my code for looping and paging the data inside the BLOB?

I set up this stream to get the paging

[image]

I created a string variable to view the PAGINATION content

[image]

When I run app logic and parse the variable, it returns this weird content instead of pages 1, 2...

[image]

When I try to configure the loop to go through all the pages I don't know what to inform the counter and the variable paging marker. How should I configure this part?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `@equals(body('Lists_blobs_(V2)')?['nextPageMarker'], '')` use `@equals(variables('pagination'), '')`.
2. Before the end of the `Until` loop, set the `pagination` variable to `Next page marker` from `Lists blobs (V2) 2` (the action inside the loop).